# I applied SQL Server SP2 but SSMS displays 11.0.3153 still

Tags: sql-server, patch

The SQL Server version I'm running is 2012 (11.0.3153) in our dev environment..

I've just applied SQL Server SP2 to my database but the version appears unchanged. I need the version level at 11.0.5058 to match our production.

There was no errors during the installation.

Any idea what's going on?

Select @@version shows:

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3153.0 (Intel X86) 
    Jul 22 2014 15:41:01 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)

However I tried applying the patch again and I get this:

Upgrade Status: Installed.

There's not supposed to be a need for a restart but I'm doing that anyway.

Restart did not work either.

Comment: Did you refresh the Object Explorer?

Comment: Yeah I totally disconnected and connected back actually.

Comment: plz do not hate me, but i need to ask you stupid question. are you sure that you install SP2? can you download and install it again https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43340

what edition you have? Express? Developer?

Comment: This is the file I downloaded. There are no stupid questions. Also I would love that this would be the problem :)

SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU

Comment: so yeah I clicked your link. Definitely it.

Comment: do you have multiple instances of SQL Server on your machine?  Regardless, go into the SQL Server setup/log folder (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.110).aspx) to see what was and wasn't installed.